# MacOS Catalina PPTP.ppp is missing

Tags: catalina, pptp

Latest macOS Catalina update has removed PPTP.ppp plugin, rendering PPTP VPN connections impossible. Has anybody found a solution to this? Can the PPTP.ppp plugin be manually installed?

I know PPTP VPN has been deprecated a long time ago, but my employer is unwilling to upgrade.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: my employer actually caved and moved to L2PT. Possibly this is actually the only solution here, and perhaps fair play to Apple for forcing the nuclear option on those hanging on to an insecure protocol. PPTP is effectively dead on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that there is no solution at this point. PPTP is no longer supported by MacOS natively and is removed from the kernel. Some providers are popping up (https://www.vpntracker.com/us/download.html#vpnt365) but otherwise move to another protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I tested VPN Tracker with PPTP last night and it's functional.

Answer (score 0):

+1 VPNTracker works like a dream.  We had to enable MPPE or MPEE? encryption in the VPN router before it would work.  Using UTT ER4240 VPN Router

Answer (score 0):

There is a [workaround](https://filipmolcik.com/pptp-vpn-on-mac-os-x-catalina-for-free/).  Use the Linux [PPTP Client](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml).

However I couldn't get MPPE to work.  But I'm sure it's possible, as VPNTracker and PrimoVPN do it.